# PipelineStorage IOError: [Errno 21]

Tags: python, django, django-pipeline

I started using Django, and I wanted a SASS compiler so I found django-pipeline. I followed the steps in [this](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tutorial and managed to get to the collectstatic step. When I run the command

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

and type 'yes' I get this error: 
(whole traceback)

```
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 167, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 118, in collect
    for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 26, in post_process
    packager.pack_stylesheets(package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 96, in pack_stylesheets
    variant=package.variant, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 106, in pack
    content = compress(paths, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 73, in compress_css
    css = self.concatenate_and_rewrite(paths, output_filename, variant)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 137, in concatenate_and_rewrite
    content = self.read_text(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 216, in read_text
    content = self.read_bytes(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 210, in read_bytes
    file = staticfiles_storage.open(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 33, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 160, in _open
    return File(open(self.path(name), mode))
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: u'/home/vedran/Development/django/blog/collectstatic'
```

Here's my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for blog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#35hy+0t97*x8sgk5yf91ff3_my8u9ljs5-p^jxb3l0i0zc9^)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'moj_blog',
    'pipeline',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates', ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'blog',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/vedran/Development/django/blog/collectstatic'
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yui.YUICompressor'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'


PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'colors': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'style.css'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'colors.css',
    },
}
```

I have installed Yuglify as well. The error occurs when this line is in the settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
```

Deleting it I don't get any errors and all the files are copied to the STATIC_ROOT directory, but somehow I feel that that line is important and should be omitted.